# Is there a way to calculate flow accumulation in google earth engine with python?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I see that Earth Engine has 'ee.Terrain.slope()', but is there a way I can use another python library to calculate flow accumulation - like in pyDEM or pygeoprocessing?

Comment: There is a flow accumulation asset available at WWF/HydroSHEDS/15ACC

Comment: Thanks @blindjesse. Unfortunately 15 arc-seconds is too coarse for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a 3 arc-second flow accumulation dataset available via:

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('users/imerg/flow_acc_3s').mean()
```